# JQuery Dropdown Menu "immediately" closes when it drops down on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, navigation

have got this problem when i click on my "hamburger icon" in mobile view..it drops down the mobile nav, but...then immediately slides it back up instantly? This is code that i have not written so finding it hard to decipher...any help would be great.

Here is the code I am working with....

```
General.nav.init = function() {
jQuery(".mobile-opener").on("click", function(a) {
    a.preventDefault(), jQuery("#main-nav .primary").slideToggle(), jQuery(this).toggleClass("open");
}), jQuery("#nav").scrollToFixed({
    minWidth: "1024"
});
```

and the code it targets....

```
  <div class="purple" id="nav">
<nav id="main-nav" class="container">
  <a href="#" class="mobile-opener"></a>
  <ul class="primary">
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Find an event</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Organise your own event</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pull-right secondary">
    <li class="blue-item"><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
    <li class="green-item"><a href="#"><span class="mob-hide">Get your </span>fundraising pack</a></li> 
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**update it only seems to be effecting when viewed on mobile device, it works ok in browser?

Comment: Can you post your "open" class from css. Try to remove slideToggle or toggleClass

Comment: Please share working code

Answer (score 0):

Try `a.stopPropagation()` instead of `a.preventDefault()` on line 3

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this didn't fix it